# Invoking WebService using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, invoke

I want to invoke a service from javascript and then to display the response data in html file. Is it possible? Have anyone done this before? Any pointers or solution will be helpful. Thanks

Request Message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:log="http://login">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <log:validateLogin>
         <log:login>
            <log:password>password</log:password>
            <log:username>username</log:username>
         </log:login>
      </log:validateLogin>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Response Message:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <validateLoginResponse xmlns="http://login">
         <validateLoginReturn>true</validateLoginReturn>
      </validateLoginResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need to create the request soap message, send it to service, and read the response.

Comment: is web service on different domain?

Comment: What kind of webservice? Rest-based services are no problem, when they support JSONP. Your main obstacle will be the same origin policy.

Comment: @GovindKamalaPrakashMalviya, Yes Webservice is on different domain, so  looking to get thro' it

Comment: @Ahamed, you can'r call cross domain Ajax (only ajax is option to call any service from javascript), you can use only JSONP for cross domain, you have to use server side scripting for soap web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
var id=1;
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '../webservice.asmx/yourmethod',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data:{'id':id}
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function () {
    //show wait
    },
    success: function (msg) {
        if (msg.d != null) {
        //result is obtained
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Where do I have to send the request strings, say logon credentials?

Comment: @Amritpal Singh, I just tried as you mentioned, but getting javascript error as follows. `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/Service/services/GreetingService/getWelcomeMessage. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.` How to resolve this. I am doing for test service, which is hosted in localhost. Apache tomcat server 1.7.

Comment: I think you are trying cross domain webservice for that you just check the link http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/calling-cross-domain-web-services-in-ajax/

Answer (score 1):

see http://www.local-guru.net/blog/2010/1/24/calling-webservices-from-mootools-jquery-or-dojo